# Saving files in Folder with a folder name as date

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sqlite, t-sql

I would like to know how to save a pdf file in a folder which is created with the date as its name.
I have to save the pdf in the folder just created.

Here is my code as is:

```
DECLARE @SP VARBINARY(MAX),
@DT VARCHAR(MAX),
@OT INT,
@Rr varchar(30),
@PL varchar(100),
@fL varchar(100)
SET @fL = 'L' + REPLACE(CONVERT(varchar(10), GETDATE(), 101), '/', '')
set @PL = 'c:\'+ @fL
EXEC master.dbo.xp_create_subdir @PL


SET @DESTPATH = '@PL' + CAST(@Rr AS varchar) + '.pdf'
EXEC sp_OACreate 'ADODB.Stream', @OT OUTPUT
EXEC sp_OASetProperty @OT, 'Type', 1
EXEC sp_OAMethod @OT, 'Open'
EXEC sp_OAMethod @OT, 'Write', NULL, @SOURCEPATH
EXEC sp_OAMethod @OT, 'SaveToFile', NULL, @DESTPATH, 2
EXEC sp_OAMethod @OT, 'Close'
EXEC sp_OADestroy @OT
```

Comment: Perhaps you could give us a clue as to the current behavior and what the problem is.  Do you receive an error? Do your .pdfs not appear?

Comment: PDFs do not appear in the folder and there are no errors either

Comment: Sorry maybe i do not understand well, but i think that `@DESTPATH` is wrong, because this have `@PL = 'c:\'+ @fL + CAST(@Rr AS varchar) + '.pdf'` and should be `@PL = 'c:\'+ @fL + '\' + CAST(@Rr AS varchar) + '.pdf'`. I think you're missing the **'\'**.

Comment: still the folder is empty :(